# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i m trying to call web services method from android app but i get in error java.lang.RuntimeException error occured while executing doInBackground() and the app stopped i have saw alot of question about this but they solved by adding internet permission to the manifest file but its Didn't work to

here is my code

```
package com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.adapter.JsonAttractionAdapter;

public class KaranganyarAttractionFragment extends Fragment {

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    // JSON Node names
    public static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
    public static final String TAG_PICPATH = "PicPath";

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList;
    ListView list;

    JsonAttractionAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_karanganyar, container, false);

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new LoadTask().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void loadAttraction(){
        attractionList = new 
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
            JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/getWisata/id/1", "GET", params);
            // JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://192.168.56.1:8080/examples/json.html", "GET", params);
            // looping through All messages
            for (int i = 0; i < attraction.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = attraction.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String nama = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                String picPath = c.getString(TAG_PICPATH);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, nama);
                map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                map.put(TAG_PICPATH, picPath);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                attractionList.add(map);
            }

            adapter = new JsonAttractionAdapter(
                    getActivity(), attractionList);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            loadAttraction();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("JSON", "TEST");
            Log.i("JSON", attractionList.toString());
        }       

    }

}
```

and the logcat

```
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionFragment.loadAttraction(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:74)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionFragment.access$0(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:63)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionFragment$LoadTask.doInBackground(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:110)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.yeftaandrea.plesirsolo.KaranganyarAttractionFragment$LoadTask.doInBackground(KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:1)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-02 09:35:33.245: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     ... 4 more
```

I need your help, thank you

Comment: figure out whats null here `KaranganyarAttractionFragment.java:74`

Comment: line : 74 is " creating new HashMap " @tyczj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check attraction!=null before doing the for loop

```
JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/getWisata/id/1", "GET", params);

if(attraction!=null){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: so I moved the code after JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/getWisata/id/1", "GET", params); inside if ??

Comment: Not inside the if, you need to surround the loop with the if, and execute the loop if and only if `attraction!=null`

Comment: its error was gone, but the data does not appear , the logcat : Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: That URL is not returning JSON, is returning HTML

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your variable `atraction` is `null` because this call

```
JSONArray attraction = parser.makeHttpRequestArray("http://plesirsolo.meximas.com/plesir/attraction/wisata/getWisata/id/1", "GET", params);
```

is returning `null`, and later you are trying to access that variable in

```
for (int i = 0; i < attraction.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = attraction.getJSONObject(i);
```

Check that before accesing the object `attraction` it is initialized or if it is `null` do not enter the `loop`. You should also read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510)